# Table Generation using Itext in given format

Tags: java, itext

I want to generate a table like this using itext:

[image]

Where the first column has numbers like 1,2,3..... The second column has attributes name like--name, roll no, etc... and last column has actual data corresponding to each attribute.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2

Comment: @RyanTheLeach OK, but that's iText 5. As the OP is new to iText, why not use the most recent version iText 7? The code to create PDFs using iText 7 is very different from the iText 5 code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to iText, you should use the most recent version of iText. That's iText 7.0.3: https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases

You want to create a table that looks like this:
[image]

That table was created using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("table.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Table table = new Table(new float[]{1, 4, 4});
    table.setWidthPercent(50);
    table
        .addHeaderCell(
                new Cell().add("A")
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER))
        .addHeaderCell(
                new Cell().add("B")
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER))
        .addHeaderCell(
                new Cell().add("C")
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        table
            .addCell(
                    new Cell().add(String.format("%s.", i))
                    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)
                    .setBorderTop(Border.NO_BORDER)
                    .setBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER))
            .addCell(
                    new Cell().add(String.format("key %s", i))
                    .setBorderTop(Border.NO_BORDER)
                    .setBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER))
            .addCell(
                    new Cell().add(String.format("value %s", i))
                    .setBorderTop(Border.NO_BORDER)
                    .setBorderBottom(Border.NO_BORDER));
    }
    table
        .addFooterCell(
            new Cell().add("A")
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER))
        .addFooterCell(
            new Cell().add("B")
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER))
        .addFooterCell(
            new Cell().add("C")
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

The `pdf` object is the low-level PDF document that writes PDF syntax to the `PdfWriter`. We use the `pdf` object to create a `Document` instance named `document`. That is the high-level document to which we can add all kinds of building blocks such as `Paragraph`, `Image`, `List`, and other high-level objects.

In your case, we want to add a table, hence we create a `Table` instance. We pass a `float` array with three elements because we want three columns. The width of the first column is 1/4th of the width of the second and third column. We want the table to take 50% of the available width on the page.

Now we are going to add cells. You can add three types of cells:

- Header cells: using the `addHeaderCell()` method,
- Body cells: using the `addCell()` method, and
- Footer cells: using the `addFooterCell()` method.

If a table doesn't fit the page, it will be distributed over different pages, and the header and footer cells will be repeated.

The parameter passed to one of these methods is a `Cell`. We can change the alignment, the border, etc... of each cell. For more info on the properties that are available, read the [tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) and the [API documentation](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/).